# making bold etaremune item numbers, any idea?

Tags: latex

```
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{C\arabic{enumi}}
\begin{etaremune}
\item A
\item B
\item C
\end{etaremune}
```

and I would like the number in the items to become bold, however I don't know how.. the command which works for enumerate (see below) doesn't work!

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\arabic*}]
```

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite the `labelenumi` command like this:

```
  \begin{etaremune}
    \renewcommand\labelenumi{\bfseries\theenumi}
    \item etaremune
    \item etaremune
    \item etaremune
  \end{etaremune}
```

### **Update**

---

To add a `.` after the numbers, simply add a dot into the curly braces.

```
  \begin{etaremune}
    \renewcommand\labelenumi{\bfseries\theenumi .}
    \item etaremune
    \item etaremune
    \item etaremune
  \end{etaremune}
```

Comment: thanks, one more thing, how to put a dot after the item number?

Comment: yes simple add a dot in the curly braces of the \labelenumi. I update my answer - please vote it if it helps

Comment: It helps, but I cannot still vote, since someone has to vote for my questions as well.. so that my reputation increases; nevertheless I accepted your answer!